# Confused about using Google API with Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm learning how to use Fetch and have this code to get YouTube video details which works just fine:

```
const fetchPromise = fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VIDEOID&part=contentDetails&key=MYKEY');
```

Now if I try to pass my key as a parameter like this:

```
const fetchPromise = fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos', {
  key:'MYKEY',
  id:'VIDEOID',
  part:'contentDetails',
  method:'GET'
});
```

It doesn't work. I get an error:

> "The request is missing a valid API key."

My question is why does the API completely ignore the parameters I'm passing? Is my format wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

The second argument to `fetch` is "An object containing any custom settings that you want to apply to the request."

It **isn't** a collection of key-value pairs to include in the query string. `fetch` doesn't have an option for that.

If you want that, use [the URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```
const data = { 
  key:'MYKEY',
  id:'VIDEOID',
  part:'contentDetails',
};
const base_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos";
const url = new URL(base_url);
Object.entries(data).forEach( ([key, value] => url.searchParams.append(key, value) );
const fetchPromise = fetch(url, {
  method:'GET'
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see! I read the documentation and completely misunderstood that part. Thank you so much, been trying to figure it out for a while now, haha.